# Check value in List of type class

Tags: flutter

If I have two Lists of a class type, how would I go about testing to see if the values in one list appear in the other? I thought I could just use List.contains, but that didn't seem to work. I have posted my work below

```
Class TestClass {
    String property1;
    bool property2;

    TestClass({this.property1, this.property2});
}

Class StatelessWidget {

    List<TestClass> list1 = [TestClass(property1: "1", property2: false), TestClass(property1: "2", property2: false), TestClass(property1: "3", property2: false)];
    
    List<TestClass> list2 = [TestClass(property1: "2", property2: false), TestClass(property1: "3", property2: false)];

    void function {
        for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
            if (list2.contains(list1[i].prop1))
                print(list1[i].prop1);
            else
                print("-------");
        }
 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to directly compare the values. You can't directly compare Objects.

```
for (var j = 0; j < list2.length; j++){
   for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        if (list2[j].prop1.contains(list1[i].prop1))
            print(list1[i].prop1);
        else
            print("-------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to either override `==` and `hashcode` for object comparison or you can use [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package.